# How to deal with the "make install" error?

Tags: command-line, compiling, make

I have a source code and I have to compile it to have some .exe files. When I compile it by running the `make install` command, these messages appear in the terminal:

```
if [ ! -d /opt/YHyM/ ]; then mkdir /opt/YHyM/; fi 
if [ ! -d /opt/YHyM/bin/ ]; then mkdir /opt/YHyM/bin/; fi 
if [ ! -d /opt/YHyM/data/ ]; then mkdir /opt/YHyM/data/; fi 
if [ ! -d /opt/YHyM/utl/ ]; then mkdir /opt/YHyM/utl/; fi 
if [ ! -d /opt/YHyM/utl/gradssc ]; then mkdir /opt/YHyM/utl/gradssc; fi 
cp -pu  bin/* /opt/YHyM/bin/ 
cp: omitting directory `bin/BTOP' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/DataPreparation' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/SW' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/YHyM_SNOW' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/YHyM_Sup' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/asc2vlm' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/calc_extra_pds' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/calc_extra_pds2' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/calc_srmax' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/subset_GIMMS' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/subset_cru1' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/subset_cru2' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/subset_cru3' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/subset_glcc' 
cp: omitting directory `bin/subset_pal_ndvi' 
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just a vague guess:

```bash
cp -pu  bin/* /opt/YHyM/bin/
```

That won't copy whole directories and results in an error, such as

```bash
cp: omitting directory `bin/BTOP'
```

Did you try to use the -r option of the cp command

```bash
cp -pur  bin/* /opt/YHyM/bin/
```

instead?

Btw, would it make sense to you to shorten the generation of the directory tree using

```bash
BASEDIR="/opt/YHyM"

if [[ ! -d ${BASEDIR} ]]; then
    mkdir -p ${BASEDIR}/{bin,data,utl/gradssc}
fi
```

Comment: @minerz029 Thanks for adding the syntax highlighting! I wasn't aware of that feature.

Comment: Sure, [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) for more details about how it works.